Python3-pip installation failing me countless times in ubuntu 22.04
I keep getting a security message that stops python3-pip from installing.
I have tried almost everything,but I still get the same issue.
Error message:
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libexpat1-dev amd64 2.4.7-1ubuntu0.2
404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/expat/libexpat1-dev_2.4.7-1ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

error message

Assuming you already tried apt-get update --fix-missing and it didn't fixed the broken url, try and install the missing package from here:
https://answers.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security-proposed/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/24859730
dpkg -i libexpat1-dev_2.4.7-1ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb

